# What's the significance of this book?

Tags: analysis, mank

This book appeared so many times in the movie [Mank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mank):

[image]

What's the significance of this book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written on it, it's a notebook. This hard-cover top-spiral model is still widely used, with or without brand/logo/texte on the cover.

As a screenwriter, you expect the person to have lots of ideas, lots of writing, and to put in on paper as soon as it comes to mind.

Just like a journalist, secretary, student... taking notes. If you focus on the drawings on the notebook in your picture, you'll see what looks like a meeting and a secretary, people taking notes.

On your screenshot, notebooks are even piled up, making them look like a "*library of thoughts*". They were just the forebears of modern electronic pocket recorders. [image: top-spiral notebooks]